# Cloudfront url rewrite using lambda@edge

Tags: c#, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I want to have friendly paths for my images. 
For example:
"https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/images/friendly-file-name-132456.jpg"

But, actually the pysical path in S3 is:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/132456.jpg"

More or less same as AWS example:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-edge-workshops/blob/master/Workshop1/Lab4_PrettyUrls/README.md#2-uri-rewrite

How do I implement a lambda@edge function that catches the request to S3 and modifying the file path?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda@Edge doesn't support c# yet.
I tried to deploy basic function to Lambda@Edge and I received an error that currently only NodeJS runtime is supported.